Why are inodes in a tree if they don't contain file names?
Something I am a bit confused on is why directory inodes exist, if inodes don't contain file paths/names why order them in a hierarchy?

Inodes aren't in a tree.  Filenames (and diriectories are just files) are in a tree, and a filename points to an inode, but the inode isn't in the tree.  If you use a tool such as debugfs then you can access the inode directly.

You're confusing things – inodes aren't in trees. I mean, they might appear in some tree structures on some specific file systems, invisible to the user. But that's an implementation detail of that specific file system, not API.
(Here comes my usual rant: the fact that POSIX exposes inode numbers to user space is a mistake. You can't really open a file by its inode – you need to search all nodes in a file system until you find the list of all files (thanks to hardlinks) or the directory with that inode number, and by that time, the original file might have long been deleted and a new one created with the same inode number. So, they are useless for identifying files, and they expose an assumption on the underlying data structure to the user that simply isn't true for all file systems.)
So, files as identified by file names are in what is a directory tree¹ to the user. Files as "identified" by the inode number aren't.

¹ actually, when you think about it, a file system isn't even a tree. With hard links, a file can have multiple paths through the graph to the file system root – that's not a tree, that's a directed acyclic graph.

With file hard links, maybe "find the list of all files with that inode number".

From what I have read directory inodes exist and contain pointers to both file inodes and sub directories.

Also where is the directory information stored on the disk if not in the inodes?

@FourierFlux Suppose you have an array of objects, and those objects internally refer to other objects in the array in a tree-like manner, but the placement of those objects in the array has no relation whatsoever with those internal references. If someone asks you what data structure is the objects stored in, do you answer array or tree?

@FourierFlux counter question: Linux can mount FAT32 filesystems. These have directories. And although ls -i will show some inode numbers, there's simply no concept of inodes in FAT32. Inherently, the idea of "directories must be stored in inodes" cannot be right, because directories are stored there, but inodes do not exist. And that's also the reality of most modern UNIX file systems, which do have inodes; for example, for directories with more than some entries, XFS will store the references to entries in a directory in a structure stored in data blocks, not in metadata blocks (inodes).

@FourierFlux as muru illustrated: The file names are stored in the file system (and you don't know how specifically they are stored; it doesn't matter to you as user), and they "logically" form a tree-like structure (the filesystem tree, with directories and subdirectories). Entries in that tree-like structure have the property "refering to an inode". How, whether and where these are stored is a separate question – again, invisible to you as user, and irrelevant. And, typically, not a tree.
